# How to recover deleted-recovered windows efs-encrypted files?

Tags: file-encryption, decryption, file-format

I'd some EFS-encrypted files on a HDD which were deleted unintentionally. I used a data recovery software to restore them, but afterward, windows does not recognize those recovered files as encrypted anymore. I've pfx which files were encrypted with, but I'm unable to use it. Is there any way to recover my data?

Comment: Ask at Superuser : [EFS encrypted](https://superuser.com/search?q=EFS+encrypted)? And, that is why backups are always required.

Comment: Or you already asked almost 3 years ago [How to decrypt a recovered EFS file](https://superuser.com/q/1177352/428106)

Comment: @kelalaka yes, but I haven't found the solution, yet...

Comment: The easiest place a bounty on it